# How to count the difference between number from one cell and SUM of the column from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have database of the different courses. My aim is to count an amount of free places on any course. I have an attribute in one table, which shows how many people can be on course. And in another table I have information about the students, where I can see which course student is studying. So, probably I should count the difference between the umber of all places and count amount of students on course.

I did the query in the following way:

```
SELECT (classes.amount_of_students - (SELECT COUNT(id_class) 
                                      FROM classes_students 
                                      WHERE id_class = 1)) AS free_places 
FROM classes 
  INNER JOIN classes_students ON classes.id_class = classes_students.id_class;
```

But unfortunately I have the following error:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying - bigint
LINE 1: SELECT (classes.amount_of_students - (SELECT COUNT(id_class)...
                                           ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

So, what's the problem and how can I solve it?

**UPD**

```
classes_student

 id_class | id_student 
----------+------------
        1 |          1
        2 |          2
        1 |          3

students

id_student |  name  |  last_name   |      email      |   login   | password 
------------+--------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+----------
          1 | Serhei | Mikhailovski | serega@mail.ru  | serzh     | 12345
          2 | Bogdan | Zaitsev      | zaitsev@mail.ru | bodyaga   | qwerty
          3 | Vadim  | Yachin       | yachin@mail.ru  | yanchilla | 13371488


CREATE TABLE classes_students (
    id_class SERIAL REFERENCES classes (id_class),
    id_student SERIAL REFERENCES student (id_student),
    PRIMARY KEY (id_class, id_student)
);

    CREATE TABLE classes (
    id_class SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    amount_of_hours VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    amount_of_students VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    id_subject SERIAL REFERENCES subject (id_subject),
    id_teacher SERIAL REFERENCES teacher (id_teacher)
);
```

Comment: Please share the table schema of  `classes` and `classes_students` too.

Comment: The error message tells you that you are trying to subtract a number from a character string. Which in turn means that `amount_of_students` is a column of type `varchar`. But if you want to store numbers in that column it should be defined as `integer` or `bigint`

Comment: @rad, updated the question

Comment: You are missing the definition of the `classes` tables which contains the column with the wrong data type

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, sorry, my mistake, fixed the tables in question

Comment: **NEVER**, ever store numbers in `varchar` columns. Fix your data model and convert those columns to `int`. Additionally: the foreign key columns should **NOT** be defined as `serial` but as a simple `integer` type.

Comment: Yes, I changed it,  now it selects needable number, the result is `free_places -------------- 7 7 7` But I don't understand why it is shown 3 times. What's the matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @a_horse_with_no_name commented on your post, you are trying to subtract a `number` from a `varchar` in the line:

```
(classes.amount_of_students - (SELECT COUNT(id_class)
```

Because `classes.amount_of_students` is of type `VARCHAR`.
Therefore you need to either alter the table column `amount_of_students` of `classes` and change its type to `int`:

```
ALTER TABLE classes
ALTER COLUMN amount_of_students TYPE INT
```

Or `cast` it to `integer` in your query:

```
(nullif(classes.amount_of_students, '')::int - (SELECT COUNT(id_class)
```

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot, now it selects needable number, the result is  `free_places 
--------------
            7
            7
            7`
But I don't understand why it is shown 3 times. What's the matter?

Comment: Glad it helped. That's an issue with the query and better to be asked in a new post.